# Contact form with PHP Mailer, which refreshes whole page when clicking Send

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I did contact form with PHP Mailer, JavaScript and Ajax call

Everything works fine, expect javascript after clicking on button. (I even recieve an email sucessfully)

My html code:

```
                                <form id="contact-form" class="contact">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="fullname" placeholder="Fullname">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email adress">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button id="gumb" type="button" class="btnc" onclick="validateContact();">Send</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>

                            </div>      

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div id="response_brought"></div><!-- This will display the response from the server -->
                                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            </div>
```

JavaSript code (This works fine, but after i press button, I RECIEVE EMAIL but my last response stays the same.. it doesn't change. It display response from fullname=="" ('Please enter your fullname in the required field to proceed. Thanks.').. **So I guess there is an error inside Ajax** call

```
function validateContact() {
"use strict";
var valid = true;

var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
var formData = {
    fullname: $("#fullname").val(),
    email: $("#email").val(),
    message: $("#message").val(),
};
var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
var emailreg = $("#email").val();
var message = $("#message").val();

    //dataString = {'fullname': fullname, 'email': email,   'message': message, 'submitted': '1'};

if (fullname === "") { //Validation against empty field for fullname
    $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="form_info" align="left">Please enter your fullname in the required field to proceed. Thanks.</div>');
    $("#fullname").focus();
    valid = false;
} else if (emailreg === "") { //Validation against empty field for email address
    $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="form_info" align="left">Please enter your email address in the required email field to proceed. Thanks.</div>');
    $("#email").focus();
    valid = false;
} else if (reg.test(emailreg) === false) { //Validation for working email address
    $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="form_info" align="left">Sorry, your email address is invalid. Please enter a valid email address to proceed. Thanks.</div>');
    $("#email").focus();
    valid = false;
} else if (message === "") { //Validation against empty field for email message
    $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="form_info" align="left">Please enter your message in the required message field to proceed. Thanks.</div>');
    $("#message").focus();
    valid = false;
} 
valid = true;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "sendemail.php",
data: formData,
success:function(data){
    var response_brought = response.indexOf('Congrats');
    $(".contact-form").slideUp(500);
    $("#response_brought").html(response);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#response_brought").html('');
    }, 10000);
    },
    error:function (){}
});
}
```

Error in my console: [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V4pD.png)

And my php code:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require_once 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require_once 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require_once 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";

//$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = True;

$mail->Host       = "smtp host";
$mail->Username   = "myemail";
$mail->Password   = "****";

$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->Port = '587';

$fullname     = $_POST['fullname'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$success = $error = '';

if (!empty($fullname) && !empty($email) && !empty($message)) {

    try {
        $mail->setFrom('myemail');
        $mail->addAddress('myemail');
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'Mail poslan iz spletnega obrazca';
        $mail->Body = "Ime: " . $_POST["fullname"] . "<br> Email: " . $_POST["email"] .         "<br>";
        $mail->Body .= $message;
        $mail->send();
        $success = "Message sent successfully";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = "Sorry message could not send, try again";
    } 
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `response` should be `data` in your js function.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you be more specific pretty please

Comment: `response` is not defined per your error message. `data` is so `$("#response_brought").html(data);`

Comment: Ohh okey great now it works thank you!.. BUT how can I now set up in ajax response, that if mail IS NOT SENT that it display that mail is not sent.. please answer me just this now

Comment: In the simplest terms you can `echo` the status from your PHP. Whatever is echo'd would get put in your div. So `echo $success;` or `echo $error;`.

Comment: I found a problem in my code.. My AJAX now looks like this:
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sendemail.php",
    data: formData,
    success:function(formData){
       
        $(".contact-form").slideUp(500);
        $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="form_info" align="left">Thank you for your email.</div>');
        },
        error:function (){}

    });

So every time i click button it shows me function for ajax success (thank you rfor you mail ) ..
Can you help me how to set up a code to check in  response if mail is sent and then gives response